# Easy way to limit file size (stdout) on a shell script level?

Tags: bash

Ok, this is a very practial use case from my point of view.

Let say I have a some simple shell oneliner which does log the output into a file. This can be simply anything, for example tcpdump. Is there any generic and trivial way, to make sure, that the output file won't exceed given size?

Resoning behind this, is to protect from filling the whole available space on the mount point by mistake. If I forget about the script, or it will yield GBs of data per hour, then this simple debugging task can lead to a potential system crash.

Now, I am aware of the options build in some of the tools (like combination of -W/-C in tcpdump). What I need is a very generic failsafe.

Long story short - when I run a script like:

```
% this -is --my=very|awsome|script >> /var/tmp/output.log
```

How to make sure that output.log will never get bigger than 1GB.

Script can crash, be killed or whatever.

Solution I am looking for should be easy and simple, using only tools available in popular distros like ubuntu/debian/fedora. In general something widely available. Complicated, multiline program is not an options here regardless of the language/technology.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `head` for this:

```
command | head -c 1G > /var/tmp/output.log
```

It accepts K, M, G and the like as suffixes (bytes are the default). Append 'B' to use the base 10 versions.

Comment: *head agains wall* It couldn't be more simple. Thanks!

Comment: It seems `tail -c 1G` also works, useful to look at the tail of an event. Understandably it flushes after the command end.

Comment: Unit for suffixes do not work on Mac OS.

Comment: Sticking my neck out here, but this does not seem to accomplish what the OP requested (yes - i realize he accepted it, but read the question). He is using an append redirect (`>>`), and asks, `How to make sure that output.log will never get bigger than 1GB.` This answer does not do that - this answer limits the size of the command output to 1G. Tested on macos using repetitive `env | head -c 1000 >> /var/tmp/output.log` which yielded: `-rw-r--r-- 1 seamus wheel 7304 Dec 25 03:33 output.log`

Comment: Hi, I wanted to ask will this allow the latest changes within the 1GB or will it stop adding the changes after 1 GB.

Answer (score 3):

curtail limits the size of a program's output and preserves the last X KB of output with the following command:

run_program | curtail -s 1G myprogram.log

https://github.com/Comcast/Infinite-File-Curtailer

NOTE: I'm the maintainer of the above repo. Just sharing the solution...

Comment: Hi Dave, I have tried your solution and it works very well, but is there a way I can go ahead and see the output of the provided program as well on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Set the maximum file size for a user that will only be used to run these scripts.

The file `/etc/security/limits` limits a user with the values of "default" unless there are explicit values for a specific user.  These user specific values will overwrite the default values.  The file may have a slightly different name depending on your OS.

If your log user is named log_maker, then add this line to the file:

`log_maker    hard    fsize    1000000`

The number after fsize is the maximum file size in KB.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit any file with

```
tail -c 1G myLog.log > myLog.tmp
mv myLog.tmp myLog.log
```

*Writing the tail directly to the same file makes an empty file. So you need to use a temporary file.*

Comment: tail -c 1G myLog.log > myLog.tmp
    mv myLog.tmp > myLog.log this will kill the log, i think you wanted to use >> instead of > or dont you?

Comment: The purpose of this command is to rewrite the log with only the last 1G. The >> should be for the previous command : doSomething >> myLog.log; tail -c 1G myLog.log > myLog.tmp; mv myLog.tmp > myLog.log;

Comment: IMHO, your answer comes closest to answering the OP's question. Oddly, the selected answer does not seem to answer the question (see my comment above). But I believe your answer contains a flaw: there is no redirect `>` in `mv`; it's simply `mv myLog.tmp myLog.log`, not `mv myLog.tmp > myLog.log`

Comment: You're right. Just corrected this typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like Seamus said inside Eduardo Ivanec answer, this questions seens to ask about how to continuously update into a file, like doing a backup from a external [journalctl](/questions/tagged/journalctl).

1. Write a [cutter.sh](/questions/tagged/cutter.sh) script, to limit your file size
   Note: This method is *allows* the output file to be larger than specified between the sleep interval.

|    #!/bin/sh

```
MY_FILE="myJournal.log"

while true; do
  echo "$(tail ${MY_FILE} -c 400)" > ${MY_FILE}
  sleep 1
done
```

2. Run the [cutter.sh](/questions/tagged/cutter.sh), and keep it running:

   ./cutter.sh &
3. Run your script/application pointing to file, ex:

   journalctl -f >> myJournal.log